# Detecting one image within another and returning it's value

Tags: c#, image

I have a dictionary of pattern images for many letters and I also have a bitmap that has to be recognized! Heights of "both" images are the same! Some Pattern images have different width.

How to iterate over X axis and recognize letters from pattern?

Right now I'm using this function to Check if X bitmap column has Black pixels in it:

```
static Boolean GetColumnState(Bitmap bmp, int x)
{
    BitmapData pixelData = bmp.LockBits(
      new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height),
      ImageLockMode.ReadOnly,
      PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
    Boolean state = false;
    unsafe
    {
        int* pData = (int*)pixelData.Scan0.ToPointer();
        pData += x;
        for (int i = 0; i < bmp.Height; ++i)
        {
            pData += bmp.Width;
            if (Color.FromArgb(*pData) == Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0, 0))
            {
                state = true;
                break;
                //pixelColumn[i] = Color.FromArgb(*pData);
            }
        }
    }
    bmp.UnlockBits(pixelData);

    return state;
}
```

If `GetColumnState()` returns True, then I crop an image of the same size as pattern image and compare them.

```
        int y = target.Count;

        for (int i = 0; i < b1.Width; i++)
        {
            if (GetColumnState(b1, i + count) == true)
            {
                        int trWidth = target[5].Value.Width;
                        int trHeight = target[5].Value.Height;
                        Bitmap bitm = new Bitmap(trWidth, trHeight);
                        Rectangle section = new Rectangle(new Point(0, b1.Height - trHeight-1), new Size(trWidth, trHeight));
                        Bitmap cropped = CropImage(b1, section);
                        cropped.Save(@"C:\111.png");
                        target[5].Value.Save(@"C:\000.png");

                        if (CompareMemCmp(cropped, target[5].Value) == true)
                        {
                            //count = target[5].Value.Width;
                            textBox2.AppendText(target[5].Key);
                            break;
                        }
                        else { textBox2.AppendText("noo"); }

                //textBox1.Text = "yes!";
            }
            else
            {
                //textBox1.Text = "noo";
            }
            break;
        }
```

Unfortunately, even though Cropped image visually looks the same - it has different size so memcmp (my method of comparison is based on this) returns *false*..

Bitmap that has to be recognized and Pattern images are all in BlackAndWhite colors.. I'm  wondering if there is a more reliable way to compare one image within another Image and return its value through dictionary(OCR)..

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C#" and such. That's what the tags are for.

Comment: ok, I also use C# tag to ease up searching.. I always thought that here are people that are professionals in different programming languages, so I entered C# on purpose in order NOT to attract PHP, C++ or Java people.. but anyway I'll take it as a warning and won't repeat this mistake in the future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pattern matching based on pixel values is not robust, as you have discovered. If the font is completely predictable and consistently rendered, you can make this work by normalizing the images (align, scale, rotate to match), and computing the mean square difference between the images, then accepting if it's small enough.

In the face of unknown fonts, or varying image sources (screencapture, camera, scan, etc), you need a more robust scheme based on some type of machine learning (ML). Recognizing digits from bitmaps is a classical introductory example to neural networks, but many other ML schemes will work - see [Supervised learning#Approaches_and_algorithms on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supervised_learning#Approaches_and_algorithms). Note that this will involve training, implying you need a good diverse set of data to train it on.

Comment: I'm planning on using it to recognize known font.. all letters always have the same pixels, etc. I've managed to do the recognition with 100% result but it took nearly 1 second to recognize just 4 letters. ;( I'll be asking one more question about optimization.. If the speed isn't good enough even then - I use Tesseract or other solution..